# Sample from a regular expression

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

How do I generate random strings that match a regular expression with quickcheck?

In such a way that the regex (i.e. the corresponding finite automaton) generates the strings. (And not: generate some random strings that are then filtered by a regex)

Ideally, the resulting distribution of strings should be uniform with respect to the set of strings (i.e. the regular language) that is generated by the regex (where the length of each string is bounded by a constant).

Comment: Nothing like this currently exists afaik.

Comment: Uniformity isn't feasible when you have infinite languages and strings of unbounded length.

Comment: In which way are you definining regexes? It shouldn't be that hard to create a data type for them and then an `Arbitrary` instance. You have to implement the various operators, but for the basic stuff it shouldn't be that hard. The problems will appear with things like lookahead/lookbehind but may be workable.

Comment: Just generating bare-bones regular languages is already possible with basic QC combinators (`oneof` for choice, `listof` for star, `liftM2 (++)` for concatenation).

Comment: @AndrásKovács, I am fine with strings of bounded length.

Comment: You may be interesting in [Enumerating the strings of regular languages](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/nfa.ps.gz). If you can enumerate the entire language as say a list, then simply uniformly sampling from that list gets you the uniform distribution property you want (for finite languages at least - not sure how what you want for that. Strictly speaking Probability(x) = 0 for all x in L if the language is infinite)